# css disapears when trying to create clean url's

Tags: php, css, html, .htaccess

I'm trying to implement clean url's to my website, but I've runned into a problem. When i'm trying to load just the default url feks: www.example.com, everything works as it should, but when i try changing it like this: www.example.com/home/, everything loads except my images and my css.

Just some testing html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
     <p>just an example text</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

My htaccess file:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use absolute links:

```
<link href="http://www.example.com/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

or add in the `<head>`:

```
 <base href="http://www.example.com/">
```

or

```
 <base href="/">
```