# PHP .htaccess username redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have dilemma for my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?user=$1
```

Example:

When I open `http://example.com/david` it opened as well.

But if I add slash after username, it won't open, like `http://example.com/david/` (note the trailing slash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?user=$1
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried. When I open http://example.com/david can't open. When open http://example.com/david/ <-- with / that opened but the css not function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ user.php?user=$1
```

And for css:

[css disapears when trying to create clean url's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173191/css-disapears-when-trying-to-create-clean-urls/27173363#27173363)

(Do not accept a solution if it does not work!)