# Can't load css, js and images when using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a "mysite.com" and I want when it loads to load contents from the "mysite.com/new-site" folder. 
My .htaccess now looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(/)?$ new-site/ [L]
```

And it loads the html but withoute any css, js or images. How can I tell the htaccess to load them from the new-site directory ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css disapears when trying to create clean url's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173191/css-disapears-when-trying-to-create-clean-urls)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*/)*([^/.]+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js|images))$ /new-site/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

EDIT:

Here's a bit more code with a little explanation so you can notice where everything is on your server.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "index.php"
RewriteRule ^index.php$ public/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule . public/index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*/)*([^/.]+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /public/assets/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

So at first it says to search for index.php ( in your case it could be index.html or anything else where the site starts at first), after that it says to redirect to folder public/ on the server, since idex.php is located in /www/public or /public_html/public, in your case it could be /www/new-site/ so you'd do new-site/ in that part of the code, next add the same for . so new-site/index.php or whatever it is in your case. On the last part it says to search for files that end with jpg/jpeg, gif, bmp, png, tiff, css or js in /public/assets/, in your case it could be new-site/assets/ or just new-site/.

Hope this clarify's it a bit.

Comment: Can you tell me the exact path on the server for js/css, etc? e.g. /www/public/assets/css, it should be something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.exemple\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://exemple.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^((?!new-site/).*)$ /new-site/$1 [L]
```